# Converting binary string to 32bit floats with Python sometimes shifts the decimal place

Tags: python, arrays

I'm reading out my sensor values via a protocol closely resembling Modbus RTU using Python. Sometimes, two consecutive values have their decimal point shifted by one place, say I read a voltage of 538.154 in one packet and on the next packet it shows 53.963, which I know is off by a factor of ten as the voltage is stable. I'm not really good at programming and am not sure if it is my python code or a problem in the sensor.

The above two values originate from these packets (only first few bytes given, voltage is the first value after id, function code) which I store in a variable called answ:

```
1:   b'\x04\x03 \xc58D\x06\x89\xd9>\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00n~<\xd9\x11\xb4K [....]'  
(correct voltage)

2:   b'\x04\x03 \xa1\xf4BW\xda(>\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf6\x0f@\x16\x01.D [....]'  
(off by factor of 10)
```

(The voltage values described are the first values in the 'payload' of both packets.)

I remove the header information via

```
data = answ[5:37]
```

first and then try to get the floating point values by

```py
helper = 0
for i in range(0, len(data) ,4):
    try:
        global_vars.sensor_vals[helper] = float(struct.unpack(">f", bytearray(data[i:i+4]))[0])
        global_vars.sensor_vals[helper] = float("{:3.3f}".format(global_vars.sensor_vals[helper]))
        helper = helper + 1
```

Please excuse my crude Python code.

I also tried different approaches like bytes.fromhex(...) instead of bytearray, but with the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or does the sensor show me wrong values?

Best regards & Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Your code for unpacking is correct (it will either always or never work), which is all that we can say. If you are getting unexpected results, then either the format is different than you expect, or the results are in a different range than you expect – but we cannot say which is true.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! Thanks a lot!